# How can I make Verilog HDL ModelSim test bench for a simple ripple adder circuit output an addition table instead of a long list of every calculation?

Tags: fpga, verilog, modelsim, code, testbench

I've completed my assignment and I'd like to make the output look something like this, with one table for sum output and one table for carry output:

```
Sum:
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15
    __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __
1 | 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16
2 | 3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
3 | 4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
4 | 5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
...
15| 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Is this something that could be easily achievable?

Here's my main file, `RCA.v`:

```
module RCA(CIN,A,B,S,C);

    input CIN;
    input wire [3:0] A,B;
    output wire [4:0] S;
    output wire [3:0] C;
    
    CA bit0 (CIN, A[0], B[0], S[0], C[0]);
    CA bit1 (C[0], A[1], B[1], S[1], C[1]);
    CA bit2 (C[1], A[2], B[2], S[2], C[2]);
    CA bit3 (C[2], A[3], B[3], S[3], C[3]);
    assign S[4] = C[3];

endmodule

module CA(cIn,a,b,s,cOut);
    
    input a,b,cIn;
    output s,cOut;
    
    assign cOut = (a & b)|((a ^ b) & cIn);
    
    assign s = (cIn ^ (a ^ b));
    
endmodule
```

And this is my current testbench file, `tb_RCA.v`:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module tb_RCA ();
    reg [3:0] A;
    reg [3:0] B;
    reg CIN;
    wire [4:0] S;
    wire [3:0] C;

integer i;

RCA uut (
    .A(A),
    .B(B),
    .S(S),
    .C(C),
    .CIN(CIN)
);

initial begin
    for(i=0; i < 2**8; i = i+1) begin
        {A,B} = i;
        CIN = 0;
        #5;
        $display( "%d + %d = %d | %d", A, B, S, C );
        #5;
    end
end

endmodule
```

The testbench output looks like this right now, where the first two numbers are each number to be summed, followed by the sum and the carry bit at the end:

```
 0 +  0 =  0 |  0
 0 +  1 =  1 |  0
 0 +  2 =  2 |  0
...
15 + 13 = 28 | 15
15 + 14 = 29 | 14
15 + 15 = 30 | 15
```

I'm not very experienced with programming, but I know enough to at least get me this far. I think that this could be fun to learn. Any guidance or references to external instructions would be greatly appreciated. I would also appreciate any comments on what I have presented here that could help me write better Verilog code.

Thanks!

Comment: Store the table in an array, and print out the array at the end of the simulation in the format you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested `for` loops for the body of your table, and another `for` loop for the header.  To show numbers within a line (and avoid the newline character), use `$write` instead of `$display`.  Use `$display` to end a line.  Refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2017](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/system-verilog/info), section 21.2.1 *The display and write tasks*.

```
integer i, j;

initial begin
    $write("     ");
    for (i=1; i <= 15; i = i+1) begin
        $write("__ ");
    end
    $display;

    for (i=1; i <= 15; i = i+1) begin
        A = i;
        $write("%d | ", A);
        for (j=1; j <= 15; j = j+1) begin
            B = j;
            CIN = 0;
            #5;
            $write("%d ", S);
            #5;
        end
        $display;
    end
end
```

Output:

```
     __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ 
 1 |  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
 2 |  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 
 3 |  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 
 4 |  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
 5 |  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
 6 |  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 
 7 |  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 
 8 |  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
 9 | 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 
10 | 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 
11 | 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
12 | 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
13 | 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 
14 | 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
15 | 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

---

I'll let you have the *fun* of printing the header numbers and a table for the carry output :)